# Control C only flags in Bazel cc_library rule

Tags: bazel

Is there a way to control conly flags from a cc_* rule?

The only way I found is using the command line when invoking Bazel, but that is for the whole session.

copts in a cc_* rule will be used for both C and C++ and I only need certain C flags for C code.

Comment: Take it with a grain of salt please, but my understanding so far is that as of current state you would need a to define two rules (sets of rules) for C and C++ respectively to tackle the problem you've described. Macros could come handy for that: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/macros.html

Comment: This is currently the solution I'm using, but it requires developers to stop using the native cc_library rules and only go through the macros. If the option does exist on a global scale why not in a rule base scale. I was hoping for a "hidden" undocumented feature (bazel has lots of these :) )

Comment: I'd also be interested to learn if I've missed something, hopefully one of the gurus could shed a bit more light here. For now, to make this easier on our developers, my plan of action is to give them the rules (macros) they need. E.g. `cc_*` and `cxx_*`. Since we use custom toolchain, I can package the necessary bzl definition with the SDK we provide.